# How to add a debossed effect to text in a highly textured image using CG-methods in Swift

Tags: swift, effects, cgrect

I have to write some text on a custom `CGRect` with a highly textured in a `CGContext`.

This has work for dark and for light images. The texture has to be visible at the *debossed* letters.

**Current approach**

1. calculate avg. color of background image
2. darken (related to the luminance) the color
3. `CGRect.drawText...` with the ID with color of 2.
4. add a darker ouster shadow to text
5. add a light inner shadow to text
6. done.

**Problem**

My current approach works for dark, slightly textured backgrounds but it does not work for dark strong textured backgrounds.

**Example usecase**

Render license plates with an embossed ID for a car app.

or

Dog tags (see [wikimedia](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e5/South_African_Navy_WW2_dogtag.jpg))

Comment: Could you add or link to an example image?

Comment: I updated my post with a link to a wikimedia dog tag (other use case) image

Comment: So your are interested in a photorealistic look?

Comment: Yep. It should be look like *this could be a real sign*.

Answer (score 0):

It was a rough play with background color of the material, background color of the embossed thing and 4 different shadows.

All in all I have (sorry for that) no 'how to do it' solution. Thanks for your help.